# BringIntoView method doesn't work for inner Expanders

Tags: c#, wpf, expander

I have a WPF application with multiple Expanders

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        <Expander Header="OuterExpander1" Expanded="ExpanderExpanded">
            <StackPanel>
                <Expander Header="InnerExpander1" Expanded="ExpanderExpanded"/>
                <Expander Header="InnerExpander2" Expanded="ExpanderExpanded"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
        <Expander Header="OuterExpander2" Expanded="ExpanderExpanded">
            <StackPanel>
                <Expander Header="InnerExpander3" Expanded="ExpanderExpanded"/>
                <Expander Header="InnerExpander4" Expanded="ExpanderExpanded"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>

private void ExpanderExpanded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Expander).BringIntoView(new Rect(0, 0, 0, 1000));
}
```

But BringIntoView method doesn't work for inner Expanders, how could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a x:Name for the Expanders. It seems to solve the problem for me !!